# Declaring first, downcasting later

Tags: swift, downcast

Say I have `BaseClass`, `DerivedClassOne`, `DerivedClassTwo`, a magical factory method `giveMeAnObjectOfType(type: String) -> BaseClass`, and the following code

```
func myBeautifulFunction(index: Int) -> BaseClass {
    let type : String = self.someArray[index]
    var anObject : BaseClass

    switch type {

    case "TypeOne":
        // This won't work
        anObject = self.giveMeAnObjectOfType("DerivedClassOne") as! DerivedClassOne
        anObject.methodOfDCOne()

    case "TypeTwo":
        // Neither will this
        anObject = self.giveMeAnObjectOfType("DerivedClassTwo") as! DerivedClassTwo
        anObject.methodOfDCTwo()

    default:
        // Throw a tantrum here
    }

    return anObject
}
```

This will result in errors saying that anObject does not contain either `methodOfDCOne()` or `methodOfDCTwo()`. Question: how do I cast my objects properly?

Basically, I could achieve the same by having several return statements within the switch's cases, but I don't like how that looks. Besides, if I wanted to call some methods of `BaseClass`, I'd have tons of repeated code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
anObject.methodOfDCOne()
```

does not compile because `methodOfDCOne` is not an instance method
of `BaseClass` (or its superclasses).

You have to create objects of the subclass type first so that you can call the subclass methods. Then assign (upcast) the object to the base class
variable:

```
func myBeautifulFunction(index: Int) -> BaseClass {
    let type : String = self.someArray[index]
    let anObject : BaseClass

    switch type {

    case "TypeOne":
        let dc1 = self.giveMeAnObjectOfType("DerivedClassOne") as! DerivedClassOne
        dc1.methodOfDCOne()
        anObject = dc1

    case "TypeTwo":
        let dc2 = self.giveMeAnObjectOfType("DerivedClassTwo") as! DerivedClassTwo
        dc2.methodOfDCTwo()
        anObject = dc2

    default:
        // Throw a tantrum here
        fatalError("Unexpected type")
    }

    return anObject
}
```

Comment: OK, that solves it. Is there something in particular from the docs that I can read up on this to clarify why this is happening?

Comment: @Morpheu5: Why what is happening? If `anObject` is declared as an instance of `BaseClass` then you cannot call subclass methods on it.

Comment: No, I get that. I guess I was getting confused by some old code that I remembered differently. Anyway, thanks :)